# How do I externalize a default property value of a custom annotation

Tags: spring, annotations

Lets say I have a custom Annotation like below:

```
public @interface myLimits {

    int MIN_LIMIT = 400;

    int stockLimit() default MIN_LIMIT;
}
```

Instead of hard-coding the value of MIN_LIMIT in the annotation definition, can we externalize it to a properties file?

Something like below - Assuming "min.limit" is defined in a properties file.

```
public @interface myLimits {

    @value("${min.limit}")
    int MIN_LIMIT;

    int stockLimit() default MIN_LIMIT;
}
```

How do I externalize `MIN_LIMIT` instead of hard-coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking: you can't. Annotations are processed in a separate compile round before the rest of the code, which means that everything that appears anywhere in an annotation must be a compile-time constant.

[Here's what the JLS has to say about it:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#255114)

> An element type T is commensurate with an element value V if and only
>   if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - T is an array type E[] and either:
>
>   - V is an
>       ElementValueArrayInitializer and each ElementValueInitializer
>       (analogous to a variable initializer in an array initializer) in V is
>       commensurate with E.
>   - Or V is an ElementValue that is commensurate with
>       T.
> - The type of V is assignment compatible (§5.2) with T and,
>     furthermore:
>
>   - If T is a primitive type or String, V is a constant
>       expression (§15.28).
>   - V is not null.
>   - if T is Class, or an invocation of Class, and V is a class literal (§15.8.2).
>   - If T is an enum type, and V
>       is an enum constant.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the element type is
>   not commensurate with the ElementValue.

Comment: Thanks, for your quick reply and also for editing my question (this is my first question here). Do we have any other way around to achieve the externalization of the property values?

Comment: You would have to write a custom component, perhaps a BeanPostProcessor or a BeanFactoryPostProcessor